# How to prevent users from seeing data that does not belong to them in Django DetailView?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a web app where a user signs in and begins entering items for a `ToDoList`. The `base.html` is wrapped in an `is_authenticated` check so users cannot see anything in the app until they have logged in. I was doing some testing with:

- Logging in as `User2`
- Adding a new `ToDoListItem`
- Redirecting to the `DetailView`
- In this case, the URL = `http://localhost:8000/to_do_list/to_do_item/72`

At this point I realized that the DetailView would allow `User2` to see the details for any `ToDoListItem` for `User1` just by entering in an existing `pk` into: `http://localhost:8000/to_do_list/to_do_item/<int:pk>`.

## urls.py includes

```
path('to_do_item/<int:pk>', views.ToDoListItemDetail.as_view(), name='todo-item-detail'),
```

## views.py

```
class ToDoListItemDetail(DetailView):
    model = ToDoListItem
```

## todolistitem_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<a href="/">Home</a>
    <h1>DetailView for 'ToDoListItem' model</h1>
    <p>TaskTitle: '{{ object.title }}'</p>
    <p>Complete: '{{ object.is_complete }}'</p>
    <p>User: '{{ object.user}}'</p> 
{% endblock %}
```

What is the recommended way to prevent this from happening? I am considering the following:

1. I could completely remove the DetailView and direct to a different URL that only returns the user's data (using something like `ToDoListItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)`)
2. I could check that the name of the user logged in matches the name of the user that owns the `ToDoListItem`.
3. I could override `get_context_data()` for the DetailView and check user ownership there (similar to no. 1, but within the DetailView)
4. ??? (Something else better than the above I do not know about yet)

Is there a way to limit a user to only see their own data throughout an application without implementing this logic every time it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *filter* in the `DetailView` as well, by overriding the [**`get_queryset`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ToDoListItemDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = ToDoListItem

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ToDoListItemDetail, self).get_queryset(
            *args, **kwargs
        ).filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Django will, behind the curtains, always call `get_queryset(..)`. By default this function returns the queryset of the `model` you specified with all objects. But you thus can filter it further down.

Django's [**`get_object`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) will then further filter it down with the `id` and/or `slug`, but if you already filter out the elements that do not belong to the `self.request.user`, then this can thus only result in an query returning no results.

It also makes sense to here add the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) to your class, since in case the user did not log in, you probably want to redirect hem/her to the login screen.

Comment: I have a function based view with a pk for a model `def addItemToModel(request, model_id):`. How can I use a mixin or something for this. If there are no solution for this, I will just make an if statement inside the function based view. I only want the user who owns the model to be allowed to add items to this model.

Answer (score 0):

There is a permission named: ¨can read¨ that allow you to handle the access. For example:

```
class FruitEdit(PermissionRequiredMixin,DetailView):
      permission_required = 'app.read_fruit'
      ...
```

I hope you can solve it